# Django form with dynamic number of items depending on other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to generate a dynamic form for the models below (some fields removed for brevity):

```
class BreakfastOption(CreatedUpdatedByMixin, TimeStampedModel):

    """Option for breakfast, e.g. white bread, brown bread, tea, coffee"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    BREAKFAST_CATEGORY_CHOICE = (
        ('food_week', 'Food during week'),
        ('food_weekend', 'Food during weekend'),
        ('drinks', 'Drinks'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=BREAKFAST_CATEGORY_CHOICE, )


class BreakfastOptionChoice(CreatedUpdatedByMixin, TimeStampedModel):

    """Option for breakfast along with its desired quantity, e.g. 2 slices of white bread and one tea"""

    breakfast_option = models.ForeignKey(BreakfastOption, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()


class BreakfastPreference(CreatedUpdatedByMixin, TimeStampedModel):

    """Person's choice for breakfast, e.g. 2 slices of white bread and 1 tea, along with comments"""

    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)  # Used for tracking changes
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(BreakfastOptionChoice)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

What I'd like to have is a form for `BreakfastPreference` where the user can see the whole list of available `BreakfastOption`s (which are about 8) and can enter a quantity for those, along with overall comments.

Example form:

- Person: (prefilled through URL)
- "White bread slices" quantity: 2
- "Brown bread slices" quantity: 0
- "Tea" quantity: 1
- "Coffee" quantity: 0
- Comments: person wants breakfast as early as possible

In the above example, rows 2 to 5 are dynamically generated (i.e. there could be 4, but at a future point there can be 5 or more choices).
Once submitted, following items are saved:

- One `BreakfastPreference`s for person X and comments Y with `choices`
- Two `BreakfastOptionChoice`s: White bread slide with quantity 2, and Tea with quantity 1

I have used formsets before, but this doesn't seem to fully fit the purpose, as I'd only get a few `BreakfastOptionChoice` objects. I could set the quantity to the exact number of `BreakfastOptions` available, but then the user would still need to pick each choice from a dropdown which is prone to error and loses the overview.

Am I modelling my models in a wrong way? Any pointers on how to best approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this kind of model:

```
Model BreakfastPreference:
    user : FK to User
    start_date : Your Date
    options : MTM field to BreakfastOption with through table
    comments : String Field

    
Model BreakfastPreferenceOptions:
    user : FK to User
    break_fast_preference : FK to BreakfastPreference
    quantity : Integer Field
    price : optional field ?
    comment : Comment per option ?
```

it's so much like a shopping website user selects some items and enters a quantity for the selected item and the backend saves them to her basket after adding some comments to her basket pushing it to pay ...,
The only thing you need is for it shows a list of option and give a quantity and after that add these items to her basket ( BreakfastPreference ) after that add the quantity and other stuff to BreakfastPreferenceOptions without any limiting.
for reference use this [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)  of Django for ManyToManyField and through table ( middle table )

Comment: Thanks for thinking along. The through table is something to explore indeed. But what about the form?

Comment: @SaeX there are many way if get order in the admin you can simple use custom form and template and use JS to add more field and data to your POST data and simple in the save method use them , and you can do it from your views , I hope this explanation  give you a insight